# c# google speech to text api result quality is not good

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I'm using speech api for speech to text in Hebrew. I'm using C# client library with api key. In your site https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/ it works well, but in my application the quality of dictation is much worse.

I took code from your examples:

```
Config = new RecognitionConfig()
{
    Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
    SampleRateHertz = 16000,
    LanguageCode = (LangMode==LanguageMode.Hebrew)?"he-IL": "en-US",
    //EnableWordTimeOffsets=true,
    MaxAlternatives = 1
},
InterimResults = true,
SingleUtterance = false
... 
if (result.IsFinal)
{
    foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Why it can be?

Comment: Are you sending the *exact same file* via the web site and in code? I'd expect the results to be the same.

Comment: Yes. It is realtime speech by microphone. I'm saying same texts and the difference is significant at all of them.

Comment: It's possible that's a difference in how the microphone is recording in the browser vs whatever you're using in C#. I suggest you record a file and provide that *exact same input* to both the site and the C# code. That would be a more reliable test. (And then you could make the file available for us to test as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using NAudio ? I agree with Daisy. I think that you need to test with exact same input. A couple of weeks ago, i solved this problem, changing some NAudio parameters, maybe it can help you ;)

Comment: waveIn = new WaveIn();

Comment: waveIn.BufferMilliseconds = BUFFER_MILLISECONDS;

Comment: waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(16000, 1);

Comment: That's the WaveIn configuration .. BUFFER_MILLISECONDS constant i'm using 3000.

Comment: That's the request configuration:

Comment: Encoding =
                            RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                            SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                            LanguageCode = "pt-BR",